# Fastest way to convert U~[0,1) to index of 1000 items

Tags: javascript, node.js, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Say I generate a uniform random number `[0,1)`, what is the fastest way to convert that to index of 1000?

One way is to multiply by 1000 and then take the floor:

```
const u = Math.random();
const index = Math.floor(1000*u);
```

is there a computationally faster way, perhaps with bitwise operators?

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe any bitwise OP's will give you any benefit here, mainly because 1000 is not a binary number like  16,32,64 etc..

But one area you could improve performance is in truncating the value, you can force JS to use 16bit integer, this is a hint to the JS engine that allows it to use faster 16bit Maths.

Below is an example.

On my machine I get a slight performance boost using the UInt16Array..

```
t1: 3.100ms
49950492
t2: 2.200ms
49950492
```

```js
var U16 = new Uint16Array([0]);

console.time('t1');
let v = 0;
for (let l = 0; l <=1 ;l += 0.00001) {
  v += Math.trunc(l*1000);
}
console.timeEnd('t1');
console.log(v);

console.time('t2');
v = 0;
for (let l = 0; l <=1 ;l += 0.00001) {
  U16[0] = l * 1000;
  v += U16[0];
}
console.timeEnd('t2');
console.log(v);
```

Comment: I can use a different value like 1024 or what not, doesn't have to be strictly 1000 in my case.